# How to load data only once in a React function?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I retrieve data from a GraphQL query, and I want to store only the top 5 elements in a variable before the filters are applied because I am displaying those 5 elements in a chart.
Every time I change the page in the query to retrieve more data the variable rankTop is also updated it and it gets the data from the next query, whereas I would like to keep the data I got when loaded for the first time:

```
export default function DisplayCharts() {
  var [ dataRows, setDataRows ] = useState([]);
  var [ currentPage, setPage ] = useState(0);
  var [ orderCol, setOrderCol ] = useState(null);
  var [ orderColDirection, setOrderColDirection ] = useState(null);
  var [ rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(15);

  const variables = {
      page: currentPage,
      orderCol: orderCol,
      orderDirection: orderColDirection,
      rows_per_page: rowsPerPage
  };

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(
    getAllRank,
    {
      variables: variables,
      fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network"
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if(loading === false && data){
      setDataRows(data.getAllRank.rows);
      setPage(data.getAllRank.page);
    }
  }, [loading, data, currentPage]);

  if (loading) return "Loading...";
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
  const rankTop = dataRows.slice(0,5);
  var topFive = [];
  rankTop.map((item, index) => {  //When the data is requested again, this variable takes the new data and I would like to keep the one I got when it first loaded.
    topFive.push ({
      "name": item.name,
      "age": item.age,
      "rank": item.rank
    })
  });
```

Any suggestions to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to break up your states into sub components, useState should be used once and only once per component to maintain state consistency. I had similar issues in the past and this was the culprit.

Comment: So you mean something like <NewComponent data={actualQuery}/>, and the NewComponent won't reload the data after actualQuery loads new data?

Comment: The point of hooks is to reload the component upon state change. New values in your parameters will always trigger a state change. What I mean is that generally you need to separate out the parts of your app into sub-components, so that state changes to those sub-components won't trigger state change in the entire app. After reviewing your usage of useState however, it appears as though you can collapse all of those fields into one state object. Further, you might be causing a loop with useEffect coz you are telling it to trigger when 'data' is changed but then setting data inside useEffect.

Comment: Hi @BitShift thanks for taking the time. I can't find a way to design the <NewComponent so it doesn't re-render every time the parent's data is updated it. I know there is a shouldComponentUpdate method, but I would prefer to find a better design in the components. Would you mind to give a short example of how one can prevent triggering the re-render of the NewComponent? Thanks

Comment: Hey no worries. Lemme see if I can whip something up here.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `page: currentPage` in your variables that you pass to `useQuery` but then you update the `currentPage` from the query results inside the `useEffect`. This would be fine if the values are the same, but if the results change that value, the query will get re-executed.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, collapse your list of useStates() to this:

```
const[ state, setState ] = useState(
    datarows = [],
    currentPage = 0,
    orderCol = null,
    orderColDirection = null,
    rowsPerPage = 15
);
```

Also upon closer review of your code: the problem is not that it needs to "only load once".

What you want is to use the previous state and, I assume, merge it with the current state.

What's happening is the following:

- your component loads
- useEffect triggers
- you setDataRows
- the code continues to execute, dataRows.split is assigned to rankTop
- new page restarts the above process and you lose your first 5.

The second last and last step is where you are losing the data, not further down during the map call.

Look into [useRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html). You could also utilize useCallback() which is the function component version of shouldComponentUpdate()

Some tutorials on how to use it can be found [here](https://medium.com/trabe/react-useref-hook-b6c9d39e2022) and [here](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/react-using-refs-with-the-useref-hook-884ed25b5c29)

Also, deep-merging previous state after a re-render can be done with something like:

```
const prevState = useRef();
....
....
setState({...prevState, <variable1>, <variable2>, etc...});
```

Happy coding! :)

EDIT:

Also I've just noticed that topFive is initialized locally and thus on every render. Try passing an empty array to useRef() and assigning it to topFive like so:

```
var topFive = useRef([])
....
....
topfive.push ....
....
```

Comment: Thank you @BitShift for the explanation. It makes sense but I have to use useRef() before the conditional that checks if the variable data got the graphql data already, so every time I try to use useRef before that conditional the variable with data is empty.... any work around getting the data without using a conditional? Thanks!

Comment: I've just noticed that topFive is being initialized inside the component and thus on every render. Try passing an empty array into useRef() and assigning it to topFive

Answer (score 0):

Set top rank only when not defined earlier - not calculate it on every render

```
var [ topRank, setTopRank ] = useState(null);
...
...
useEffect(() => {
  if(loading === false && data){
    if(!topRank) {
      const rankTopData = data.getAllRank.rows.slice(0,5);
      var topFive = [];
      rankTopData.map((item, index) => {  //When the data is requested again, this variable takes the new data and I would like to keep the one I got when it first loaded.
        topFive.push ({
          "name": item.name,
          "age": item.age,
          "rank": item.rank
        })
      });        
      setTopRank(topFive);
    }
    setDataRows(data.getAllRank.rows);
    setPage(data.getAllRank.page);
  }
}, [loading, data, currentPage]);
```

Comment: Pretty sure he needs to load more data, then filter and merge with new data, not just retain old data and set once. Although this would be a brilliantly simple solution!